# How do I provide images to a webview?

Tags: react-native, webview

the `<WebView/>` component supports a prop called `source` to which I may pass HTML.  since the value I pass may contain image references, how do I provide the images? e.g.

```js
<WebView
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   source={{html: '<img src="logo.jpg" /><h1>Hello world</h1>'}}
/>
```